# Using DigiCert Global Root CA in a Mosquitto MQTT SSL/TLS instance and client java application

Tags: java, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am running Mosquitto MQTT for TLS1.2 successfully with certificates generated from `OpenSSL` and using in the mosquitto configuration file.  This also involves the Java Client to manually specify the CA certificate file which connects to mosquitto

I want to use the `DigiCert Global Root CA` which exists in my Java keystore.

### Current setup

The Mosquitto configuration file for this looks like the following:

```
cafile .\m2mqtt_ca.crt

# PEM encoded server certificate.
certfile .\m2mqtt_srv.crt

# PEM encoded keyfile.
keyfile .\m2mqtt_srv.key

tls_version tlsv1.2
```

These certificates were generated using OpenSSL using the following commands:

```
# generate key
openssl genrsa -des3 -out m2mqtt_ca.key 2048

# create CA certificate
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key m2mqtt_ca.key -out m2mqtt_ca.crt

# create private key for the server
openssl genrsa -out m2mqtt_srv.key 2048

# create certificate request from CA
openssl req -new -out m2mqtt_srv.csr -key m2mqtt_srv.key

# verify and sign the certificate request
openssl x509 -req -in m2mqtt_srv.csr -CA m2mqtt_ca.crt -CAkey m2mqtt_ca.key -CAcreateserial -out m2mqtt_srv.crt -days 3650
```

And it can be consumed in a client java app using the following:

```
package acme.messaging;

import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Security;

public class SslUtil {

    public static final SSLSocketFactory Instance;

    static {
        Instance = SslUtil.getSocketFactory(
                "N:\\work\\acme\\mqtt-ssl\\messaging\\mqtt\\certs\\m2mqtt_ca.crt");
    }

    private static X509CertificateHolder loadCACert(String caCrtFile) throws IOException {
        PEMParser reader =
                new PEMParser(
                        new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(caCrtFile)))));
        X509CertificateHolder caCert = (X509CertificateHolder) reader.readObject();
        reader.close();

        return caCert;
    }

    static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory(
            final String caCrtFile) {

        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

            JcaX509CertificateConverter jcaX509CertificateConverter = new JcaX509CertificateConverter();

            X509CertificateHolder caCertificateHolder = loadCACert(caCrtFile);

            // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
            KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            caKs.load(null, null);
            caKs.setCertificateEntry("ca-certificate", jcaX509CertificateConverter.getCertificate(caCertificateHolder));
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(caKs);

            // finally, create SSL socket factory
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            return context.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

// consume
String uri = "ssl://localhost:1884";
String clientId = "1002";

final MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage();
String messageText = "Some data";
mqttMessage.setPayload(messageText.getBytes());

try (MqttClient client = new MqttClient(uri, clientId)) {
    if (!client.isConnected()) {
        final MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setUserName("acme-user");
        options.setPassword("acme-user".toCharArray());

        options.setSocketFactory(SslUtil.Instance);

        client.connect(options);
    }

    mqttMessage.setRetained(true);

    client.publish("test/writeme", mqttMessage);
}
```

### Question

Is it possible to use certificates that are based on the `DigiCert Global Root CA` in Mosquitto?

At present it exists in my Java Keystore:

[image: java keystore]

It can be exported, but not sure whether this can be used in the OpenSSL workflow correctly.  I have tried using it in the steps above but this yielded errors.  The idea being to generate the same files and import those into the mosquito configuration.

### Errors from trying to reuse the DigiCert certificate with OpenSSL

Here I did try to use the generated file and a downloaded one from [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm)

The following command line generated on [DigiCert website](https://www.digicert.com/easy-csr/openssl.htm)

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out localhost.csr -keyout localhost.key -subj "/C=GB/ST=Durham/L=Durham/O=quorum/CN=localhost"
Can't load ./.rnd into RNG
8016:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file:crypto\rand\randfile.c:88:Filename=./.rnd
Generating a RSA private key
......................................................................................................................................................................+++++
.....................................................................................................+++++
writing new private key to 'localhost.key'
```

NOTE: I am lost with my order of events here.

Then these:

```
openssl x509 -req -in localhost.csr -CA DigiCertAssuredIDRootCA.crt -CAkey localhost.key -CAcreateserial -out m2mqtt_srv.crt -days 3650
```

errors with:

```
Signature ok
subject=C = GB, ST = Durham, L = Durham, O = quorum, CN = localhost
unable to load certificate
9896:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Also tried this:

```
openssl x509 -req -in localhost.csr -CA DigiCertAssuredIDRootCA.crt -CAkey DigiCertAssuredIDRootCA.crt.pem -CAcreateserial -out m2mqtt_srv.crt -days 3650
```

errors with:

```
Signature ok
subject=C = GB, ST = Durham, L = Durham, O = quorum, CN = localhost
unable to load certificate
12904:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the errors.

Comment: I have added the  errors from earlier, although I am lost at the order of things I have tried.  I have exported the cert and tried that - but there is no exported key.  I don't know if I need that.  Also downloaded a cert and key from the digicert website.

Comment: You can't sign your own certificate with a trusted CA cert, the CA has to do it for you and NO trusted CA will EVER sign a certificate for `localhost`

Comment: Yep was thinking so.  Wanted to check thanks.  Put that on as answer and I will accept and close this off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hashed out in the comments.

You can not sign a certificate as a trusted CA (if you could why would you ever trust the CA?).

You have to generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) and send this to the CA for them to sign it (and usually charge you for it). They will also prove that you own the domain the certificate will represent. (LetsEncrypt does this all for you using the certbot tool and will do it for free).

Also no trusted CA will ever sign a certificate for `localhost`.

Comment: It was just local testing between a  MQTT and an app.  In the real world we will be testing with that DigiCert certificate.  However for now I am looking at generating the openssl certs and importing into java key stores.  Thanks for the info.