# Java SSLHandshakeException from Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors

Tags: java, security, ssl, mqtt

Following on with my adventures of [MQTT and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65027283/using-digicert-global-root-ca-in-a-mosquitto-mqtt-ssl-tls-instance-and-client-ja), I have hit an issue in my Java environment.

This time I am using `OpenSSL` generated certificates and trying to import them into my `java key store`.  I am getting an error `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors`.

I am still learning more about SSL/TLS/Certificates/Java Keystores.

### Client exception

When I run the application, I get the following error (driving from a test)

```
acme.fooApp.mqtt.FooMqttException: MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors

    at acme.fooApp.mqtt.MqttConnection.connect(MqttConnection.java:53)
    at acme.fooApp.mqtt.BasicAuthenticationWithSSLConnections.will_successfully_send_a_message(BasicAuthenticationWithSSLConnections.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:736)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:362)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:270)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:154)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:80)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:357)
    ... 16 more

Process finished with exit code -1
```

### Mosquitto Configuration

```
port 1886

allow_anonymous false
password_file .\mosquitto-auth+ssl.pwd
acl_file .\mosquitto-auth+ssl.acl

#capath
cafile .\localhost_ca.crt

# PEM encoded server certificate.
certfile .\localhost_srv.crt

# PEM encoded keyfile.
keyfile .\localhost_srv.key

tls_version tlsv1.2
```

### Certificate Generation

I am generating everything using the following scripts - so there is no manual intervention - no inputs - just run:

```
# Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser 
Set-Location (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent)
$env:Path = $env:Path + ";" + $env:JAVA_HOME + "\bin"
Clear-Host

$java_key_store_alias = "MYMACHINE"
$java_key_store_file = "MYMACHINE.jks"


#
# create ca-key
#
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:password -out localhost_ca.key 2048

#
# create ca-cert
#
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key localhost_ca.key -out localhost_ca.crt -passin pass:password -subj "/C=GB/ST=Timbuktu/L=Timbuktu/O=acme/CN=localhost-CA"

#
# create server-key
#
openssl genrsa -out localhost_srv.key 2048

#
# create server-csr
#
openssl req -new -out localhost_srv.csr -key localhost_srv.key -passin pass:password -subj "/C=GB/ST=Timbuktu/L=Timbuktu/O=acme/CN=localhost"

#
# create server-crt 
#   verify and sign: server-csr = ca-crt + ca-key
#
openssl x509 -req -in localhost_srv.csr -CA localhost_ca.crt -CAkey localhost_ca.key -CAcreateserial -out localhost_srv.crt -passin pass:password -days 3650 

#
# convert ca-cert to pfx/p12
#
openssl pkcs12 -export -in localhost_ca.crt -inkey localhost_ca.key -out localhost_ca.p12 -passin pass:password -passout pass:password

# verify
write-host "Verifying..."
openssl verify -CAfile localhost_ca.crt localhost_srv.crt


#
#
# JAVA
#
#

# create a java keystore
Write-Host "Now the Java fun begins..."


if (Test-Path $java_key_store_file) {
   Remove-Item $java_key_store_file
}


keytool -genkey -alias $java_key_store_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore "$java_key_store_file" -dname "CN=localhost-CA, O=acme, L=Timbuktu, ST=Timbuktu, C=GB" -storepass password -keypass password -validity 2000

# import certificate
keytool -import -alias $java_key_store_alias -keystore $java_key_store_file -file localhost_ca.p12 -storepass password -keypass password
```

I am unsure whether this is correct.  The validate returns ok.

```
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
...........+++++
...........................................................................................+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
Can't load ./.rnd into RNG
9156:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file:crypto\rand\randfile.c:88:Filename=./.rnd
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
..+++++
................................................................................................+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
Can't load ./.rnd into RNG
6580:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file:crypto\rand\randfile.c:88:Filename=./.rnd
Signature ok
subject=C = GB, ST = Timbuktu, L = Timbuktu, O = acme, CN = localhost
Getting CA Private Key
Verifying...
localhost_srv.crt: OK
Now the Java fun begins...

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore MYMACHINE.jks -destkeystore MYMACHINE.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid
```

### Client Java Code

Currently hacking together, sorry :(

```java
public static SSLSocketFactory forKeyStore(String filePath, String password) throws Exception {

        TrustManagerFactory defaultTMF;
        X509TrustManager customTM;
        X509TrustManager defaultTM;
        List<TrustManager> trustManagerList = new ArrayList<>();

        defaultTMF = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        defaultTMF.init((KeyStore) null);
        defaultTM = getTrustManagerFromFactory(defaultTMF);

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(fileInputStream, password.toCharArray());
        fileInputStream.close();

        TrustManagerFactory customTMF = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        customTMF.init(keyStore);

        customTM = getTrustManagerFromFactory(customTMF);

        X509TrustManager finalCustomTM = customTM;
        new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
                defaultTM.checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
                try {
                    if (finalCustomTM == null) {
                        defaultTM.checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
                    } else {
                        finalCustomTM.checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
                    }
                } catch (CertificateException ex) {
                    defaultTM.checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return defaultTM.getAcceptedIssuers();
            }
        };

        //trustManagerList.addAll(Arrays.asList(tmf.getTrustManagers()));
        trustManagerList.add(finalCustomTM);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

        context.init(null, trustManagerList.toArray(new TrustManager[trustManagerList.size()]), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    private static X509TrustManager getTrustManagerFromFactory(TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory) {
        for (TrustManager tm : trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()) {
            if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                return (X509TrustManager) tm;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

### What gives?

So currently I am only importing the CA Cert into the keystore.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated.  A lot of googling on those exceptions and on here has not yielded any joy.  I will keep looking in the meantime.  Everyones scenarios are different.  I cannot see the error of my ways in my steps above.

When debugging I noticed my cert in the `finalCustomTM` variable:

[image: debugging]

If I use `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()` then this is still the case of the same error above.

If I comment in the line `trustManagerList.addAll(Arrays.asList(defaultTMF.getTrustManagers()));`, then I get a different exception:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: Try concatenating the server and CA cert into one file (order is important, but I can't remember which way it should be) and passing it to mosquitto.